# Magic file that redirects to standard output

Tags: shell, files, pipe

Is there a magic file name that gives the following effect?

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo1 && cat /tmp/fifo1 &
$ foo --log-file /tmp/fifo
# now I can see the log as the program runs
```

I want something like

```
$ foo --log-file /proc/to_stdout
```

Comment: It would be worth specifying the OS in questions like this.

Comment: I was hoping there was an answer for all (or all usable) unices...

Comment: There isn't, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/stderr` as appropriate.

Comment: Which are symlinks to `/proc/self/fd/1` and `/proc/self/fd/2` respectively — the `/dev` entries may be absent, but the `/proc` ones are guaranteed to be there if `proc` is mounted.